# Servlets : How to display intermediary results from an servlet that runs multiple threads

Tags: java, servlets

I want to create a servlet that ping some IP's and display a html page with results. For example I want to see witch IP's are reachable from 1.2.3.4 to 1.2.3.10. 
I have a class ProrocolsSuportTester with a method isReachableByPing(String ip). 
In this case I have to test 10 IP's.  isReachableByPing(String ip) takes 3 seconds to complete = > for 10 IP's the request is done in 30 seconds and after that the data is displayed. 
It is possible to have live results? This means that after 6 seconds I see in browser 2 IP tested... after 9 seconds I have 3 IP tested....

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try {

        final String ipStart = request.getParameter("ipStart");
        final String ipEnd = request.getParameter("ipEnd");

        final PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<h2>");
        printWriter.println("ipStart=" + ipStart + "</br>");
        printWriter.println("\nipEnd=" + ipEnd + "</br>");
        printWriter.println("</h2>");

        final ProtocolsSupportTester protocolsSupportTester = new ProtocolsSupportTester();

        final AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();

        final String[] tokensStart = Utils.getTokens(ipStart, ".");
        final int first = Integer.parseInt(tokensStart[3]);

        final String[] tokensEnd = Utils.getTokens(ipEnd, ".");
        final int last = Integer.parseInt(tokensEnd[3]);

        for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {

            final int j = i;

            ac.start(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        PrintWriter wr = ac.getResponse().getWriter();
                        String currentIp = tokensStart[0] + "." + tokensStart[1] + "." + tokensStart[2] + "." + j;
                        boolean reachable = protocolsSupportTester.isReachableByPing(currentIp);

                        if (reachable) {
                            wr.println("<font color=\"green\">isReachableByPing: " + currentIp + "</font>" + "</br>");

                        } else {
                            wr.println("<font color=\"red\">isReachableByPing: " + currentIp + "</font>" + "</br>");

                        }

                        ac.complete();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SimpleServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioException);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect this construt to use more than one thread, and thus it hopefully will not really take 30 seconds. However, to flush a stream (or writer) just use the flush method. I.e. put wr.flush(); before ac.complete()